# Tracking Amazon S3 Bucket File Upload from .Net Core with Angular 8 FrontEnd

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, angular8

I'm trying to upload a file from Angular 8 Frontend -> .Net Core Controller Backend -> S3 Bucket

I need to track the progress of the upload,so that a progress bar can be displayed to the user.

```
upload(files) {
        this.file = files[0].name;
        if (files.length === 0)
            return;
        const formData = new FormData();
        for (let file of files)
        formData.append(file.name, file);
       

        const uploadReq = new HttpRequest('POST', `api/upload/uploadfile`, formData, {
            reportProgress: true,
        });
        this.http.request(uploadReq).subscribe(event => {
            if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress)
                this.progress = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
                if (this.progress == 100) {
                    this.uploaded = true;
                    this.error = false;
                }
            else if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response)
                this.message = event.body.toString();
               
        });
    }
```

On the .net Core controller,i connect to s3

```
[HttpPost("uploadfile"), DisableRequestSizeLimit]
  

  public ActionResult UploadFile()
        {
      
            try
            {
            IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client("xxx", "xxx",RegionEndpoint.USWest2);
            var file = Request.Form.Files[0];

            //string destPath = "folder/sub-folder/test.txt"; // <-- low-level s3 path use /
            PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest()
            {
                InputStream = file.OpenReadStream(),
                BucketName = "vtcleaner",
                Key = file.FileName // <-- in S3 key represents a path  
            };

            PutObjectResponse response =  client.PutObjectAsync(request).Result;

            return Json("Upload Successful.");
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                return Json("Upload Failed: " + ex.Message);
            }
        // Hello
        }
    }
```

In order to track the Progress,i'm planning to use the following approach

1. Use the low level API from s3
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LLuploadFileDotNet.html
2. Continuously track the `UploadPartProgressEventCallback` event and
   pass the value to Angular

Is this the right approach? Since the call will be an async method , how to keep track of the progress variable ?

Comment: How did you pass the event value to your angular from your backend?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you have to inform frontend about progress changing. So, you should maky kind of 'request' to you frontend. It's unsupportable by regular REST, but you can use [SignalR](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/master/src/SignalR) for this propose.
For getting information about upload propose, your idea is applicable.